# Is it more compact to use 'self' or 'this' for javascript minification?

Tags: javascript, compression, obfuscation, minify

I'm wondering which form, `bind('this')`, or `var self = this` is better for minification. It seems to me that the self form probably slims down further, because self can be obfuscated, but I'd love to hear some views on this.

I recognise that different contexts have different advantages, but I couldn't find a single clear explanation of what works and what doesn't, and why.

## Examples:

### Using 'self':

***original code:***

```
userProfile.prototype.renderSynopsis = function(data){

    var self = this;

    $synopsisDiv.on('click',function(){
        self.getProfile();          
        $('.profile-container').html(self.$view);
    });

    self.$synopsis.html($synopsisDiv);
    return self.$synopsisDiv;

};
```

***Uglify.js Minified Code:***

```
userProfile.prototype.renderSynopsis=function(){var b=this;return $synopsisDiv.on("click",function(){b.getProfile(),$(".profile-container").html(b.$view)}),b.$synopsis.html($synopsisDiv),b.$synopsisDiv};
```

> **Result Stats:** 
>   Old version: 298 characters
>  
>   New version: 203 
>   characters Saved: 95 (result is 68.1% of original)

### using 'this':

```
userProfile.prototype.renderSynopsis = function(data){

    $synopsisDiv.on('click',function(){
        this.getProfile();          
        $('.profile-container').html(this.$view);
    }.bind(this));

    this.$synopsis.html($synopsisDiv);
    return this.$synopsisDiv;

};
```

***Uglify.js Minified Code:***

```
userProfile.prototype.renderSynopsis=function(){return $synopsisDiv.on("click",function(){this.getProfile(),$(".profile-container").html(this.$view)}.bind(this)),this.$synopsis.html($synopsisDiv),this.$synopsisDiv};
```

> **Result Stats:**
>
> Old version: 285 characters 
>   New version: 215 characters 
>   Saved: 70 (result is 75.4% of original)

**Updated:** adding var to self made a huge difference!

Comment: `self = this` MUST be `var self = this` or you're operating on `window.self` and creating all sorts of bugs.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's a really obvious one eh.  I might just edit that. Of course it wasn't wrong in my original code! (I'm going to fix that too now). How embarrassing.

Comment: I prefer using `me` instead of `self` because it's compact even without minification and it's self explanatory.

Comment: @B0Andrew That's true, but now I have a third option...  ~panic!~ .  I'm glad you like 'me'.  I think I might give 'me' a try sometime. It feels kind of cheeky, but I like it.

Comment: @jfriend00 that actually changed the compression substantially, so thanks! Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Self wins!**

In the end the answer to this question is that using `var self = this;` is considerably more efficient for minification, saving 3 characters for a single use, and 3 characters for every use of `self` or `this` thereafter.

The reason being that every use of `this` is replaced by a single letter (in my example above 'b'), meaning that one character is used where four would have been, saving three characters for every occurance of `this`.

**In Detail:**

The declaration `var b=this;` is 11 characters long.

The chained `.bind(this)` is also 11 characters long.

Every time I use `self` it will be minified to a single character, eg `b`.

Every time I use `this`, minification retains the full JavaScript keyword at 4 characters.

Comment: I had this same question for minification purposes and ran a performance test. Virtually no difference in every browser I checked, and Chrome in fact ran faster with the variable! http://jsperf.com/this-vs-var-me For a public library, this can be helpful for keeping file size down after minification.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, great question. 
I think you have the answer in your question. Obviously the minified can easily obfuscate a variable into a single letter, whereas it can't do that with 'this'. 
Technically, a minifier could analyze the code and do var s = this for you, but that would change the logic in the code itself and would be bad practice.

So to answer your question- in terms of minification, it looks like a bound function with many uses of "this" in it would benefit from using a var instead.

However, you would not be saving many characters and that's not what will cause your application to be served or run faster. This will also cause you to write your code differently and may cause it to be less legible, which will cost you more developer time in the future.

These are not the micro-optimizations you should be looking for. If you asked this because you're looking to get a smaller file since you feel your app loads too slowly, then you have bigger problems to worry about.

Comment: Agree on the "bigger problems to worry about".

Comment: not so much looking for a smaller file, I guess I was pondering overheads, I probably need to look into what `.bind()` actually does.

Comment: Bind creates a new copy of the function, bound to the given scope.

Comment: I also appreciate that you almost said "these are not the droids you are looking for". It's probably nice to know that either option works okay. 'Self' is possibly more readable, but binding 'this' seems technically more valid.

Comment: @Etai - I wouldn't say that `.bind()` makes a new "copy" of the function - that's not really what it does.  It makes a new stub function that does nothing more than call the original function using `.apply()` so it can set the value of `this` and pass along the arguments.

Comment: @Etai as it transpires `self` is a lot better once I added `var` to it. Bit of an oops there.  Thanks for your help!